# AbsoluteTime::ambig: Warning: the interpretation of the string 11-12-2020 as a date is ambiguous

Tags: date-and-time

[image]

```
 TScci30clean = TimeSeries[cci30clean[[2 ;;]]]
```

> I dont understand why this shows an error ,i have changed the date format twice in excel sheet that im working on and still shows this error.

Comment: First, it's a  warning, not an error. Did you check whether the result matches what you want? Second, the message seems pretty clear to me. Somewhere in your computation the expression `AbsoluteTime["11-12-2020"]` is evaluated, and since that would be interpreted differently by different conventions, it's ambiguous. To give more guidance, we'd need to see more of your code--a minimal amount to let us reproduce the warning. Might also need to see the format of the data you're importing.

Comment: I actually formatted the data from excel after this.Thanks

Answer (score 7):

A date string such as 11-12-2020 may be interpreted as meaning 11 December or 12 November. AbsoluteTime will provide a default with a warning about the ambiguity. The actual order can be specified in AbsoluteTime.

```
AbsoluteTime["11-12-2020"] 
(* 3 814 128 000 with a warning *)
AbsoluteTime[{"11-12-2020", {"Month", "Day", "Year"}}]
(* 3 814 128 000 *)
AbsoluteTime[{"11-12-2020", {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}] 
(* 3 816 633 600 *)
```

Comment: Thanks for that